# How can I eliminate the epigraph rule?

Tags: rules, epigraphs

I use the epigraph package to define the following declaration that looks as follows:

`\epigraph{This work has appeared in:}{Max Mustermann, How the Euro will crash.}`

That looks then as follows

```
This work has appeared in:
-----------------------------
Max Mustermann, How the Euro will crash.
```

It does look okay, but I do not like the line in between.

The docu says:

> By default, a rule is drawn between
>   the text and source , with the rule
>   thickness being given by the value of
>   `\epigraphrule`. The value can be
>   changed by using the LaTeX
>   `\setlength` command. A value of 0pt
>   will eliminate the rule.

UPDATE

I am not too sure where to put this setlength command, e.g.

```
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\epigraph{This work has appeared in:}{Max Mustermann, How the Euro will crash.}
```

does not work. I get the error: Missing number, treated as zero.

Any idea how to do that properly?

Comment: Welcome! I gather from the question that you're using the `epigraph` package to generate your epigraphs rather than one of the classes which provide it automatically (e.g., `memoir`).  Would you mind clarifying that in your question for posterity?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `\setlength` it this way:

```
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
```

A complete tiny example, which compiles without error and doesn't show the line:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\epigraph{This work has appeared in:}{Max Mustermann, How the Euro will crash.}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I tried to integrate as you mentioned (see above), but still it does not work :(.

Comment: @Heinz: I added a minimal example. You could test that. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else: try to create a minimal example which raises this error.

Comment: How can one change the line for one instance, then restore the length later?